# Aggregation on output of Stream-Static Inner Joins using Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

This problem pertains to Spark 2.4.4.

I am doing a Stream-static inner join and getting the result as :-

```
val orderDetailsJoined = orderItemsDF.join(ordersDF, Seq("CustomerID"), joinType = "inner")

+----------+-------+------+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|CustomerID|OrderID|ItemID|ProductID|Quantity|Subtotal|ProductPrice|OrderItemsTimestamp    |OrderDate            |Status         |OrdersTimestamp        |
+----------+-------+------+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------------------+---------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|2         |33865  |84536 |957      |1       |299.98  |299.98      |2019-11-30 18:29:17.893|2014-02-18 00:00:00.0|COMPLETE       |2019-11-30 18:29:19.331|
|2         |33865  |84537 |1073     |1       |199.99  |199.99      |2019-11-30 18:29:17.893|2014-02-18 00:00:00.0|COMPLETE       |2019-11-30 18:29:19.331|
|2         |33865  |84538 |502      |1       |50.0    |50.0        |2019-11-30 18:29:17.893|2014-02-18 00:00:00.0|COMPLETE       |2019-11-30 18:29:19.331|
```

Where "orderItemsDF" is **streaming** DataFrame and "ordersDF" is a **static** DF.

Now, I am trying to group the result by "CustomerID" and "OrderID", like this :

```
val aggResult = orderDetailsJoined.withWatermark("OrdersTimestamp", "2 minutes").
      groupBy(window($"OrdersTimestamp", "1 minute"), $"CustomerID", $"OrderID").
      agg(sum("Subtotal")).
      select(col("CustomerID"), col("OrderID"), col("sum(Subtotal)").alias("Total Amount"))
```

But this gives me blank output when I try to see the results as :

```
val res = aggResult.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("20 seconds")).option("truncate", "false").start()
res.awaitTermination()

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+----------+-------+------------+
|CustomerID|OrderID|Total Amount|
+----------+-------+------------+
+----------+-------+------------+
```

If I do,

```
res.explain(true)
```

It says: `No physical plan. Waiting for data.`

Please help!!!

Comment: may be no data to join? seems an odd approach imho

Comment: Right before the aggregation there is data with "orderDetailsJoined" dataframe. @thebluephantom

Comment: OK, but the split between streaming and static for an object that is inherently intertwined I cannot grasp

Comment: @SarfarazHussain Could you check out the answer I posted and let us know whether it worked or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** `OrdersTimestamp` values do not seem to advance so the watermark of 2 minutes and `groupBy` of 1 minute can't do their job.

---

You use `OrdersTimestamp` to inform Spark what the event time is. If it stays at `2019-11-30 18:29:19.331` in the three events you posted, and the time does not advance, Spark simply waits till the "time" group and the watermark for late events are at `2019-11-30 18:29:19.331` + "1 minute" + "2 minutes" to pass grouping result downstream.

Comment: Thanks Jacek. Can you tell me any possible solution for it?

Comment: Simple. Just emit events with proper time or remove any time-related "barriers". In other words, why are you using watermark and window?